# javascript skrollr update window height based on dynamic content

Tags: javascript, javascript-databinding

In my project I have a long scrolling page that has a project grid. when you click on a project, I ajax load that project, then slide open a window pushing the project grid down, displaying the chosen project. Each projects will have different heights based on the content. I need the content that shows below the project grid to always show at the end of the page. Currently when the grid slides open it slides right over the "footer" content (rough example at the bottom).

The skrollr documentation says that if the window resizes, you should call the refresh function.

I run this function on init, on project grid click, and I don't see the window adjusting to the new height of the content. **The goal is to have the footer appear always a couple hundred pixels after the project grid** whatever it's current height/position.

http://caava.elusiveform.com/example.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is related to skrollr. If you want the footer to appear after the content, then make sure it's there in the document flow. You are using `position:fixed` and mix it with other stuff. I recommend to first create the page without skrollr and then add animations using [relative mode](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#relative-mode-or-viewport-mode). The `skrollr.css` file you are using is outdated, it doesn't exist any more.

After you made sure the footer is correctly placed, then you can call `refresh` to make your animations work (they depend on data-end, which changes and needs to be recalculated). In your case, that would probably be enough:

```
s.refresh(document.getElementById('footer'));
```

Btw, the skrollr documentation says

> Window resizing is handled by skrollr.

`refresh` is only needed when you change the DOM and skrollr can't detect that.

Comment: I will create a static version first as recommended. I think the lightbulb just went off... I misunderstood the css positioning in the demos as that I _needed_ to use absolute values. Thank you!

Comment: Had a 2 div toggling, and doing `s.refresh(document.body)` fixed the issue for mobile devices.